# Lack of documentation on batteries? Trying to understand why LR1130 and LR1131 aren't equivalents

Tags: batteries, documentation, coin-cell

Recently I purchased some AG10 button cells for a device I have. The device specifically calls for LR1131 batteries, but someone online told me that AG10 was equivalent (and they are in a way: [same voltage and same size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes#Silver_oxide_and_alkaline_cells).

The batteries I got in the mail say LR1130 on them, which I trust is equivalent to AG10 (see previous charts). Basically the device doesn't have enough power. It works for a few minutes and then shuts off, and other odd behavior happens when it's not working like it should. On my quest for answers I've understood now that there's quite a bit more than just voltage, but every single search I try fails to give me good information on *why* these batteries differ in a way that would keep my device from working (it works with the proper LR1131 batteries, I just have no more left).

I've noticed that the batteries appear to differ in their charge, which would suggest that maybe that's why I'm having problems. I have no battery tester to see if I was actually sold good batteries.

At this point I know quite well that I just bought the wrong batteries, and will soon buy the correct set. But how can I trust it? How can I be sure that they'll work when [other items](https://www.amazon.ca/cards-Alkaline-Battery-AG10-LR1130/dp/B01N5HZ5CR/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1493387626&sr=8-3&keywords=l1131+battery) say that they're LR1130 *and* LR1131?

Edit: Actually called for LR1131 not L1131, even though this likely doesn't change anything.

Comment: *someone online told me*... then ask this someone. Or ignore. And the "equivalency" can be interpreted in different ways. Maybe they have a different capacity? Then why would you care?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LR1131 and LR1130 are both 11mm diameter by 3.1mm thickness. That's what the 1130/1131 means. Note that the image below indicates some variance in dimensions, so both numbers are rounded anyway. L indicates alkaline cell, so the same chemistry as in your typical AA battery, just smaller. R simply means round; it's an indicator of the shape. R is by far the most common for this type of battery and I'm not actually aware of any other shape nomenclature, so it's very possible it just gets left off by some manufacturers.

[image: LR1130 dimensions]

So, in short, the two are in fact identical. I think you were sold bad batteries.

Incidentally, for a slightly better battery life, you can get SR1130/SR1131s. These use a silver oxide chemistry with a slightly (1.55V rather than 1.5V) higher voltage and slightly longer life.

Comment: So if the two types are essentially identical, why have different names? Maybe one type is newer than the other, some internal structure that doesn't affect it's usage maybe?

Comment: The standard naming format for these batteries is that the first two numbers are the diameter in millimeters (rounded), and the second two numbers are the thickness in tenths of a millimeter (again, rounded). Some manufacturers just round the number differently.

Comment: Even [more names](https://24hourbatteries.com/shop/ag10-alkaline-button-cell-batterylr54-189-l1131/)

Comment: @Felthry Ah yes, apologies. Seems that I glossed over that point in your answer. So in the end there's no need for detailed documentation because the documentation is in the name.

Comment: LR and L are not the same. You missed half the problem.

Comment: I missed that, because lacking the shape designator is uncommon. But all the R means is that it's round. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it'll be a little bit before I can actually determine if other batteries are the solution, might buy a battery tester too. But yeah it certainly clears up how they are different. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.buyabattery.co.uk/gp-alkaline-battery-l1131-lr1131-1-5v-pack-of-10-batteries.html
From Above site I found this:
The LR1131 battery is quite a popular alkaline button cell battery. Each manufacturer can have a different part numbering system and so the LR1131 button battery is also known as 189 LR54 AG10 V10GA G10A L1131 L1130 LR1130. Manufactured by GP Batteries, the LR1131 is an alkaline button cell battery and made popular by small electronic equipment including calculators. This pack contains 10 batteries. Voltage 1.5V. Customers often ask why this battery is called LR1131 L1131 and also LR1130 L1130. The answer is in the dimensions of the battery itself. The L or LR denotes an alkaline battery. The diameter of 11.6mm is where the 11 comes from. The thickness of the battery makes up the end of the part number. The normal thickness is 3.05mm and can be rounded up or down to 3.0 or 3.1 for part numbering reasons. Hence some manufacturers round up and some down. So we have LR1130 and LR1131, both of which are the same battery.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. The number part is a sizing in mm. 11 mm x 3.0 mm and 11 mm x 3.1 mm. A single 1/10 of a millimetre is so minor that it makes no difference in most holders.

But the designation L and LR are not the same. L is a substitute for CR, which is a 3V nominal lithium cell. LR is a designator for Alkaline, 1.5V nominal.

So the behavior you're seeing is because your device is starved for voltage. It's getting half the voltage.

Comment: Are you sure of this? My impression is that an alkaline cell intended to replace a lithium cell would be 2LR1131... or 2LR1115? I don't recall if the height is total or per cell.

Comment: This may or may not be true. It would certainly be a definite cause to this problem. I just looked at the flyer for my product and they actually use LR1131 and L1131 interchangeably in their documentation of it. I think that they do mean that the device needs 6 volts and not the 12 that CR1130's might. Edited my question.

Comment: @cosmineer look at Wikipedia on battery sizes. And double check the voltage with a multimeter

Comment: @felthry it's not intended to replace it, just two similarly labeled products of the same size.

Comment: @Passerby You're saying L indicates an alkaline battery intended to replace a CR cell, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: @felthry yes. See wiki's table of battery sizes.

Comment: Every source I can find other than wikipedia and the single source wikipedia cites suggests that L1130 and LR1130 are the same thing. I am wondering if wikipedia is wrong here. Note, especially, that the wiki source only lists it as "also known as" under 'CR1130'... which, given that alkaline and lithium batteries are very different, is wrong regardless.

Comment: I would also like to mention that I checked the old batteries that worked (they're dead now). They're 1.5 volts.